# How to find out which Visual Studio extensions are installed on user's machines?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, active-directory, vsix, sccm

How to find out which Visual Studio extensions are installed on user's machines?

I want to track which VS extensions are installed on users' computers in AD environment. I think that's easy when an extension installs via Windows Installer (*.msi). But what about VSIX extensions (vsixinstaller.exe)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way that I am aware of to list all installed VSIX extensions, but `vsixInstaller` has an option to generate a logfile which identifies the `extension.vsixmanifest` files it locates, and each such file is an XML that contains the relevant details about the extension (name, version etc).

To have `vsixInstaller` generate the logfile, pretend to uninstall an extension that does not exist. This may take a while, especially if multiple versions of VS are installed (the following must go all on one line).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\
   app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service>
   vsixInstaller /logFile:vsix.log /appIdName:VS /uninstall:nosuchxt
```

The generated logfile will then be `%TEMP%\vsix.log` and the `Found` lines point to the extensions that `vsixInstaller` located, for example (with root paths replaced by `%VS20xx%`):

```
vsixinstaller.exe version:
16.5.2047
...
BEGIN: Processing extension pack
...
Found '%ProgramFiles(x86)%\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
...
Found '%VS2015%\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\VSSDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
...
Found '%VS2019%\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\VSSDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
...
END: Processing extension pack
```

Each `extension.vsixmanifest` file referenced in the list begins with a `metadata` node that identifies the name and version of the respective extension, for example:

```
<Metadata>
  <Identity Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK" 
            Version="16.0"
            Language="en-US"
            Publisher="Microsoft Corporation" />
  <DisplayName>Microsoft Visual Studio SDK</DisplayName>
  <Description>Tools for building Visual Studio extensions</Description>
</Metadata>
```

With some (not entirely trivial) plumbing work, this could all be automated in a script/batch job.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the [IVsExtensionManager.GetInstalledExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dd820750(v=vs.120)) API is what you're looking for.

Also, Mad's published an open source "[Extension Manager 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager2019)" extension, that implements an export/import extensions command, which you might find as a useful example.

The source for the extension can be found in the following github repo:

[ExtensionPackTools](https://github.com/madskristensen/ExtensionPackTools)

Sincerely